# UICollectionView layout wrong in IOS 9

Tags: swift, autolayout, uicollectionview

I subclass `UICollectionViewCell` and draw graphics like below(top image) is in IOS 8.4, which works good. The cell width is equal to screen bounds width. But when i run on IOS 9, i got the bottom image below. If i swipe the cell to next then swipe back it works well like the top image. I know it's the layout in IOS9 not correct. I added:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath 
    indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
                ...
                cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
                cell.contentView.layoutSubviews()
                ...
    }
```

no help at all. Any help, thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please include the drawing code and where (and more importantly, when) it gets is size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cell.layoutIfNeeded()` solved the issue.